# Stack Level too deep when using active storage has_one_attached :picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I am trying to implement Active Storage for Ruby on Rails API project. I have placed has_one_attached :picture according to the documentation. And succeeded in uploading of picture on AWS S3 services. Now when I try to access volunteer data it says

> ```
> ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE
> ```
>
> "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND
>   "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND
>   "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id",
>   8695], ["record_type", "Volunteer"], ["name", "picture"], ["LIMIT",
>   1]]
>         ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE
>   "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>       [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with ActiveStorage::Attached::One (58.41ms)
>       Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 322ms (ActiveRecord: 48.8ms)
>
> ```
> SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
> ```

I have checked the data through rails console and image is saved in the picture attribute. Schema for volunteer is below

**Schema**

```
create_table "volunteers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "full_name"
    t.string "mobile"
    t.string "picture"
    t.boolean "kit"
    t.boolean "training"
    t.boolean "car"
    t.boolean "test"
    t.bigint "team_id"
    t.bigint "education_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.jsonb "attendance", default: []

  end
```

And when I comment out

```
has_one_attached :picture
```

in my volunteer model it works and returns me the json object without any error.

How should I solve the Stack Level too deep error?

Comment: When does this happen? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarekLipka I am trying to save an image on Amazon Web Services using Active Storage https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
Once the image is uploaded in my picture attribute and when I access volunteer "Stack Level Too Deep" error occurs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

The root cause of this problem in my case was having a field **with the same name** in my model (column in the table) as the attachment, which is not needed, since Active Storage uses separate tables. And when `to_json`
is called on such a model object, it causes Stack level too deep error.
After removing the column from the database, the problem goes away.

I see you have the same situation in your model, so i would suggest to you to remove column `picture` from the table `volunteers`

**Original Answer:**

I just ran into the same problem. For now, i solved it by omitting the attachment from json generation.
In your case, it would be something like

```
@volunteer.to_json(except: :picture)
```

or using responders

```
respond_with @volunteer, except: :picture
```

or

```
format.json { render json: @volunteer, except: :picture }
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Jauraj, And yes I am doing the same thing for now :D But that's a temporary solution.

Comment: @AhsanIhsan, please check my updated answer, i believe i found the cause and a solution to the problem

Comment: That worked. That was the real issue. Thank you so much :)

Comment: That column name was real issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here using `active_storage v5.2.8` and `rails 5.2.0`. We used as a workaround add to the model the `dependent: :destroy` and it worked too

```rb
has_one_attached :file, dependent: :destroy
```

I also find this issue with same problem:
[Attaching an ActiveStorage blob in a model callback creates a SystemStackError #37022](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37022)